Bose-Hubbard model simulation not working
I am trying to simulate a quantum system with the Bose-Hubbard model.
I have built my Hamiltonian, the initial state, the number operator matrices and everything is expressed in the same basis, so in principle there should be no problem here. Yet, when trying to time-evolve my initial state, things start to go wrong. For example, a lattice with size 5 (space for 5 bosons) and 2 bosons in positions 01000 and 00010 should give a simmetric evolution over time, since there is no side preference. But it's not working for me, one side gets more particles and so on.
I have been looking at this problem for a few days now, but solved nothing thus far. As far as I'm concerned, the theoretical-physical aspect of my program is fine. There may, be some algebraic problem going on when multiplying the matrices and the vectors, but everything I have tried failed to solve the problem.
I leave my program here, please feel free to correct any kind of problem you see. Thanks a lot before hand.
https://github.com/mikelpuy/Bose-Hubbard/blob/main/2%20particles%20new.py

Your code runs without any problem. Why do you expect another outcome and consider an issue with the code as the reason? May you provide what you are getting and show what you expect explaining why you expect it? Maybe there is an issue you need to clarify in a physics forum, not here?

Thanks for the answer. And yes, the code does run without any problem, the thing is that the answers I get from it lack any physical meaning. I have know added a plot of what I get. I should be getting a simmetric plot around the position Psi 3, but I don't. Maybe you are right and this belongs in a physics forum. Thanks anyways.

In other words you expect psi1 and psi5 as also psi2 and psi4 to look the same way in the diagram? And you designed the operations to be symmetrical with axis psi3 , but they are not? Maybe they can't? Because of psi3 which value impacts the distribution of values for the other ones? What if you model an even number of psi's?
